# Add subscribers to a group using Mailchimp's API v3 when status pending

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am currently using the API to integrate Mailchimp with an existing form on my website.

I want to add subscribers to a group. My subscribers have STATUS - PENDING and I set the interests accordingly dependent on which group I want them subscribed to.

However, I found this neither added them to the group or sent out the confirmation email. When I take the interests section out, this works perfectly and sends out a confirmation email to the subscriber.

Here is an example of the code with the group codes in.

```
$mydata = array( 
'email_address' => $email, 
'status' => 'pending' 
'interests' => array( 'groupid1' => true, 'groupid2' => false));
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to allocate subscribers to groups when the status is PENDING?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your code is just throwing an error.

> When I take the interests section out, this works perfectly and sends out a confirmation email to the subscriber.

Is it just a syntax error that's breaking the user add process?

```
$mydata = array( 
'email_address' => $email, 
'status' => 'pending', // <---- added comma here after 'status' array element declaration.
'interests' => array( 'groupid1' => true, 'groupid2' => false));
```